# Salesforce marketing cloud - calling external web service using server side activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

I am writing a Server Side activity in salesforce marketing cloud to communicate with an external web service to perform an action in a 3rd party platform. The call to the web service with the JSON payload executes successfully through postman - the web service call is recorded in a log file.

Here is a sample code which I have in the server side activity(based on marketing cloud documentation)

```
var payload = {};
payload.field_1 = "field_1";
payload.field_2 = "field_2";
payload.field_3 = "field_3";
payload.field_4 = "field_4";
var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
req.retries = 2;
req.continueOnError = true;
req.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
req.setHeader("authhash", "xxx");
req.method = "POST";
req.postData = Stringify(payload);
logMessage('Information', 'Call to post data', Stringify(payload));
var resp = req.send();
logMessage('Information', 'Call to post data', resp.returnStatus);
logMessage('Information', 'Call to post data', String(resp.content));
logMessage('Information', 'Call to post data', String(resp.statusCode));
```

The log message function is just a JS function to record the steps in a log data extension (It works fine)

Response return status recorded is 0 and status code is 0. There is no call recorded in the server log file which leads me to understand the call did not reach the server.

Any tips/help??

Regards
Sid

Comment: The status of 0 means the call was aborted, so the issue is definitely from your script somewhere. Dumb question, but you have `url` defined, right? You might also look to use the `req.contentType` instead of creating the 'Content-Type' header via `setHeader`. Here are a couple links to my blog that may also help shine more light on these functions: (https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/) and (https://gortonington.com/integration-of-sfmc-with-external-service-via-ssjs-rest-api/)

Comment: Hi @Gortonington - Thanks a lot. Moving the content type from the set header to the content type property solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Moving from Comment to Answer**

The status of 0 means the call was aborted, so the issue is definitely from your script somewhere.

I have had issues in the past setting the 'Content-Type' header via `setHeader`. I would recommend to instead use the `req.contentType` attribute.

In case you need any further assistance, here are a couple links to my blog that may also help shine more light on these functions: **[restapimethodinssjs](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/)** and **[thirdpartyintegrations](https://gortonington.com/integration-of-sfmc-with-external-service-via-ssjs-rest-api/)**